# ASP.NET MVC Custom controller not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Project called `Project.Web` which contains a folder `Mvc` which includes a base controller called `BaseController.cs`.

```
namespace ProsecVHIPHelper.Web.Mvc
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A base controller for all controllers
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class BaseController : Controller
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="applicationContext"></param>
        protected BaseController(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        {
            if (applicationContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("applicationContext");
            ApplicationContext = applicationContext;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor
        /// </summary>
        protected BaseController() : this(ApplicationContext.Current) { }

        /// <summary>
        /// The application context
        /// </summary>
        public ApplicationContext ApplicationContext
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the services singleton
        /// </summary>
        public ServiceContext Services
        {
            get { return ApplicationContext.Services; }
        }
    }
}
```

This base controller will be used by all of my other controllers.

In my second project called `Project.Web.UI` I have a route config like:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Ftp", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "Project.Web.Mvc" }
            );
        }
    }
```

Where I include the base controller namespace.

But when I create new controllers using my base controller I always get a 404 not found exception.

When I use the default Controller class then it works.

First my controllers where located in the `Project.Web` project in a folder called `Controllers`. When I add this namespace also in the route config it doesn't work.

Then I moved these controllers ( not the base controller ) to my other project `Project.Web.UI`, but still no luck.

The `Project.Web` project is a class library and the `Project.Web.UI` is a web project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found the solution. The problem was that I have added the `System.Web.Mvc` using the add reference. But this had a different version from the `System.Web.Mvc` in my web project.

After removing this reference and added a reference to the dll in the web project, everything worked like a charm!